# Can't get my form to be valid

Tags: forms, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I want to make a ReST infrastructure with a Symfony server (using FOSRestBundle). 
there is

- a **Contact** entity, (id, name, email)
- a **AddType form** to add a new contact

On the client side, I have a form which sends a POST request whose body is

**{"the_name_of_my contact_form":{"name":"foo", "email": "foo@example.org"}}**

My controller (which extends FOSRestController) can see the data in the request

**$request->request->get($form->getName())** returns **{"name":"foo", "email": "foo@example.org"}**

But whether I use **$form->handleRequest($request)** or **$form->submit($data)**

**$form->isValid()** is always false

I hope this is clear enough... can anyone help?

Comment: What does $form->getErrors() return?

Comment: Probably missing a CSRF Token? (Never used FOSRestBundle before, but if you use basic Symfony Forms this could be a reason why it fails).

Answer (score 1):

This problem is related to the CRSF validation. You have to disable it for the user requesting the service. You can disable it in you config.yml. You'll have to set something like this:

```
fos_rest:
    disable_csrf_role: ROLE_API
```

### Just make sure that the user requesting your service has this role. You can read more about user roles [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html).

Also, you'll have to submit you form, not handle it. Here is an snippet of it:

```
    $form = $this->createForm(ProjectType::class, $project);
    $form->submit($request->request->all());

    if ($form->isValid()) {
```